# Domain name SEO: worth sacrificing shorter/cooler domain for keywords? trivrank.com vs triviarank.com

Tags: seo, domains

In terms of SEO, how beneficial might it be to go with [triviarank.com](http://www.triviarank.com) for the extra "trivia" keyword?  This is for a trivia website I am constructing that gives users ranks when they answer questions.

The reason I originally went with [trivrank.com](http://www.trivrank.com) was for the coolness of calling a user's rank "trivrank".  It is also a tad shorter and half as many syllables.  I realize triviarank.com may also be more memorable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For SEO - no
2. For Branding - yes

Unfortunately keywords in the domain-name still have a slightly over-emphasized ranking weight (hopefully changing soon).

Until your brand has visibility or has reached the tipping-point with your users, I'd err on the safe side and ensure that the full-keyword domain is 301 redirected to your shorter version.

There's a couple of good case-studies to reflect on: [flickr.com](http://blog.domainsfactory.com/2010/07/at-last-flickr-com-takes-over-flicker-com-domain/) (stuck with the shorter brand) and [twitter.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter#Creation) (went from twttr.com to the word).

Comment: Thanks! I'd give you a +1, need more rep though.